# Larvae appearing after many rainy days

Tags: species-identification

After a few days of raining, I found these larvae in a puddle. What animal are they from?   [image]

Comment: Is the puddle still there? I would like a better picture, your location, and additional information like size and behaviour if possible. There are so many insects out there!

Comment: Thank you very much @picapica. But I already know what those things are. They are the final stage of the mosquito larvae. Named "pupa". I will post it as an answer (just in case some one else has the same doubt).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

They are the final stage of a mosquito larvae, called "pupa".

[image]

Comment: btw: You are allowed to mark your own answer as "accepted" by clicking the check-mark next to the up- and down buttons.